# My insert command is failing from C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have large data table and I am using an insert command to put the data into an mdb access table. I am looping through the array of columns which I got from the data table to produce the names and values for the insert command. It keeps saying I have a syntax error and I have no clue why because the syntax is fine.

```
INSERT INTO tbl01_General (PIN, PROJ_CAT, MFT, MAJFUND, OTHFUND, WORKTYPE, WORK_LABEL, FUND_DATE, ORIG_DATE, LET_DATE, MUNIC, DISTRICT, ROUTE, FROM, TO, MP1, MP2, MILES, FAS, DESCRIPTN, RESPAGENCY, CURR_PHASE, DEPARTMENT, PROJMGR, STATUS, CONT_COST, COSTBASIS, COSTDATE, BASECOST, BASEDATE, PROJ_COST, FED_FLAG, TAG_FLAG, REV_FLAG, COM_FLAG, TIP_FLAG, CON_FLAG, CON_S, CON_P, CON_D, CON_R, CON_C, CON_I, CON_O, DEPT_S, DEPT_P, DEPT_D, DEPT_R, DEPT_C, DEPT_I, DEPT_M, DEPT_L, PGM_DATE, PGM6Y_DATE, LASTUPDATE, NEEDS_TIP_INFO, SEQ_NUMBER, SELECTED, MFT_Closed_Section, SSMA_TimeStamp)   
VALUES ('B-00099', 'P', '08-00118-09-BR', 'Null', 'Null', 'Drainage', '2', '01/01/2013', '01/01/2013', '04/16/2013', 'North Barrington', 'CB-17', 'Miller Rd', '@ 0.3 mi east of', 'IL Rte 59', '0', '0', '0.3', 'Null', 'Construct 3-span Bridge and Embanked Road\r\nin order to alleviate road flooding\r\n\r\n\r\n', 'LCDOT', 'Null', 'Design', 'Construction', '', '150.0000', 'Per Al Giertych', '02/17/2011', '2600.0000', '02/17/2011', '3735.3000', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'True', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'Null', 'Null', 'Null', 'Null', 'Null', 'Null', 'Null', 'Null', '01/11/2001', '05/11/2001', '02/14/2014', 'False', 'Null', 'False', 'False', 'System.Byte[]')"
```

Syntax error with insert command

Unfortunately this also didn't work: @David

```
INSERT INTO [tbl01_General] (PIN, PROJ_CAT, MFT, MAJFUND, OTHFUND, WORKTYPE, WORK_LABEL, FUND_DATE, ORIG_DATE, LET_DATE, MUNIC, DISTRICT, ROUTE, FROM, TO, MP1, MP2, MILES, FAS, DESCRIPTN, RESPAGENCY, CURR_PHASE, DEPARTMENT, PROJMGR, STATUS, CONT_COST, COSTBASIS, COSTDATE, BASECOST, BASEDATE, PROJ_COST, FED_FLAG, TAG_FLAG, REV_FLAG, COM_FLAG, TIP_FLAG, CON_FLAG, CON_S, CON_P, CON_D, CON_R, CON_C, CON_I, CON_O, DEPT_S, DEPT_P, DEPT_D, DEPT_R, DEPT_C, DEPT_I, DEPT_M, DEPT_L, PGM_DATE, PGM6Y_DATE, LASTUPDATE, NEEDS_TIP_INFO, SEQ_NUMBER, SELECTED, MFT_Closed_Section, SSMA_TimeStamp)   
VALUES ([B-00099], [P], [08-00118-09-BR], [Null], [Null], [Drainage], [2], [01/01/2013], [01/01/2013], [04/16/2013], [North Barrington], [CB-17], [Miller Rd], [@ 0.3 mi east of], [IL Rte 59], [0], [0], [0.3], [Null], [Construct 3-span Bridge and Embanked Road\r\nin order to alleviate road flooding\r\n\r\n\r\n], [LCDOT], [Null], [Design], [Construction], [], [150.0000], [Per Al Giertych], [02/17/2011], [2600.0000], [02/17/2011], [3735.3000], [False], [False], [False], [True], [False], [False], [False], [False], [False], [False], [False], [False], [False], [Null], [Null], [Null], [Null], [Null], [Null], [Null], [Null], [01/11/2001], [05/11/2001], [02/14/2014], [False], [Null], [False], [False], [System.Byte[]])
```

Comment: You should include your error text.

Comment: What specific syntax error do you get?

Comment: I got syntax error with insert command

Comment: @JillShapiroErichsen - The field names need to be in brackets, not the values. `INSERT INTO tbl01_General ([PIN], [PROJ_CAT], ...`

Comment: Why can't you convert them all to strings? I am trying to make a dynamic insert with all the values, but I keep getting datatype conversion errors

Comment: I would put it in the Access query designer but it all has to be in c#

Comment: If I drop the quotes then I can't add it to my string though...

Comment: How else am I suppose to make an insert string for so many columns without messing up the datatyping?

Answer (score 0):

At least one of your columns names is a [reserved word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/286335).  In this case, at least the column `FROM`.  This is confusing the query parser.

In order to specify that you are referring to an *object* by that name and not using the `FROM` keyword, enclose the object names in square brackets:

```
INSERT INTO [tbl01_General] ([PIN], [PROJ_CAT], [MFT] ...
```

You don't technically need to enclose *all of them*, just the ones which would confuse the parser.  But you say that you're dynamically building the column names so that code would likely enclose all of them.

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't work. I posted in the original what you had me do.

Comment: @JillShapiroErichsen: That... wasn't at all what I suggested.  You didn't enclose the column names, but you did enclose the values.  That's the opposite of what you should do :)

Comment: True that worked better.  Thanks except it says it failed to insert due to type conversions... I guess you can't insert everything as strings..including null

Answer (score 0):

Further to bracketing many of your field names, you also need proper formatting of the date expressions, and decimals must not be quoted:

```
..., 'Per Al Giertych', #02/17/2011#, 2600.0000, ...
```